# Natural Deduction Propositional Logic

Tags: natural-deduction

How do I show that **p → q ⊢ ¬p ∨ q** is valid without using LEM (Law of Excluded Middle)?

**Edit:**

I want to know if this is okay:

\begin{align}
&\hspace{5pt}1.\; p\to q \hspace{43pt}\textrm{is given}\\ 
&\boxed{
\begin{align}
&2.\; p &\textrm{Assumption}\\
&3.\; q &\textrm{from 1}\\
&4.\; \lnot p\vee q&\\
&5.\; \lnot p &\textrm{from 4}\\
&6. \perp \hspace{12pt}&\textrm{from 5 and 1}
\end{align}
}\\
&\hspace{5pt}7. \lnot p\\
&\hspace{5pt}8. \lnot p\vee q\\
\end{align}

Comment: Can you make a truth table?

Comment: I want to use natural deduction to deduce the right side

Comment: Let me know if my edit is what you wanted.  Drawing boxes round things using MathJax and the small amount of HTML we can use in SE is horrible.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot Donkey_2009 :)

Comment: Step 5 is not allowed

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
1& & &p\to q &\text{Premise}\\
2&|& &\neg(\neg p \lor q)&\text{Assumption}\\
3&|&|&p&\text{Assumption}\\
4&|&|&q&\to\text{-elim (1,3)}\\
5&|&|&\neg p\lor q&\lor\text{-intro (4)}\\
6&|&|&\bot&\neg\text{-elim}\\
7&|& & \neg p&\neg\text{-intro (3-6)}\\
8&|& &\neg p\lor q&\lor\text{-intro (7)}\\
9&|& &\bot&\neg\text{-elim (2,8)}\\
10&&&\neg\neg(\neg p\lor q)&\neg\text{-intro (2-9)}\\
11&&&(\neg p\lor q)&\neg\neg\text{-elim (10)}
\end{array}
$$